# Were there YouTube ads calling on Russian citizens to disrupt rail routes into Ukraine?

Tags: russia, advertising, ukraine

[An address from Roskomnadzor](https://www.rkn.gov.ru/news/rsoc/news74196.htm?print=1) states "Earlier it became known that YouTube video hosting users are broadcasting commercials with calls to disable the railway communications of the Russian Federation and the Republic of Belarus. The actions of the YouTube administration are of a terrorist nature and threaten the life and health of Russian citizens."

[This video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISFVFRrXH0g&t=819s)  also apparently shows a screenshot of something on the same lines at 10:49.
However, I have tried looking for this video and have not been able to find it. Could someone verify that it exists?

Comment: Well, I'm sure that if those adds existed they were taken down quickly, as they might have violated YouTube TOS too, depending on what exactly was said in them.

Comment: I mean, there must still be a video(not as an ad) of them somewhere, though, right?

Comment: Yes, I agree, was just saying that if the Roskomnadzor claim as to the contents is correct, then I don't expect those to be easy to find. And not my DV, by the way, I upvoted.

Comment: I'm sure at least one YouTube user is saying that.

Comment: I saw one youtube (lost the reference) that said railroad workers of belarus railroad unions were committing sabotage of tracks and rolling stock to stop russian supplies arriving to attacking russian forces by train.  I think the youtube could have been from a ukranian, more or less propaganda, site.   There are a bunch of rah-rah ukranian youtube sites and a few rah-rah russian youtube sites.  Some have facts and others just make things up.

Comment: @Fizz You are far too confident of YouTube’s moderation abilities. It is very likely that an ad like this would be allowed on YouTube, and for a significant time.

Comment: Non-English moderation seems to be generally less effective.  https://prismreports.org/2021/11/02/facebook-and-youtubes-refusal-to-moderate-misinformation-in-global-languages-harms-communities-of-color/